# malloc causing heap corruption

Tags: usb, malloc, heap-memory, iokit

I'm learning how to communicate with USB devices with IOKit, and I wrote this piece of code:

```
// Global variable
char *dataBuffer;

- (void)startPolling {
  if (!shouldPoll) { // Prevent polling twice
    shouldPoll = YES;
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(poll) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(poll) withObject:nil];
  }
}

- (void)poll {
  dataBuffer = (char *)malloc(numBytes);
  numBytes = 64;

  returnCode = (*usbInterface)->ReadPipe(usbInterface, 2, dataBuffer, &numBytes);
  // Handle received data in dataBuffer

  free(dataBuffer);
  [timer fire];
}
```

It works like this: another part of the code that works fine looks for the device, opens it, and then opens the correct interface. After that, when the user presses a button, it will call `startPolling`, which will set a timer that triggers the method `poll` every 0.5 seconds (sorta, the timer will fire again repeatedly).

In the `poll` method, the program will read the USB pipe and store data on `dataBuffer`. At first, I thought that I could alloc its memory once and reuse the pointer at every iteration, but for reasons I'm unfamiliar, the second `ReadPipe` call would fail. Always.

In an act of desperation, I came up with this (terrible?) idea: allocate and free the buffer memory at every iteration. For my surprise it did work, and I was able to read the device successfully.

The problem is that from time to time the program crashes with the error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x610000005890: Heap corruption detected, free list canary is damaged
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I really don't know what that means, let alone how to solve it. I set the buffer size to 64 to make sure that any data read would fit in the memory. Actual data is 18 bytes long.

Any clues?

Comment: Damn, you're probably right (I'll be testing to make sure). It was so late, I must have been so sleepy... still can't believe that I overlooked that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, that's it. Write it as an answer so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two statements should be the other way around:

```
dataBuffer = (char *)malloc(numBytes); 
numBytes = 64;
```